# Add colored labels over the plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, label, seaborn

I was looking to recreate similar labels to these for a school project, but I can't manage to do it:

[Labels Image (Sorry I can't embbed images yet)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNwvM.png)

I am using Python's matplotlib and used the next chunk of code to generate the next plot:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(25, 15))
ax.bar(years_1960, temperatures_1960, color=colors)
sm = ScalarMappable(cmap=my_cmap2, norm=plt.Normalize(0,max(ppms_1960)))
sm.set_array([])
cbar = plt.colorbar(sm)
cbar.set_label('Cumulative CO2 emissions since 1960 (ppm)', rotation=270,labelpad=35,fontsize=20)
plt.ylabel("Temperature (degrees)",fontsize=20, labelpad=25)
plt.xlabel("Year",fontsize=20, labelpad=25)
plt.title("Global Temperature vs Cumulative CO2 emissions", fontsize=30, loc='left', pad=15)
plt.xticks(fontsize=15)
plt.yticks(fontsize=15)
plt.show()
```

[Graph Image (Sorry I can't embbed images yet)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eiXVw.png)

What would be a good source to research on how to plot such esthetic and clean labels? Or, do you have a solution that comes to mind when reading this? Thank you very much!

Comment: You can use e.g. `ax.text(x, y, 'test', color='black', backgroundcolor='salmon')`.

Comment: How do I "upvote" your comment? Anyways, it looks fantastic. Read some of the documentation and can't figure if I can change the background color alpha, know if it is possible?. Thanks!!!

Comment: You can do `from matplotlib.colors import to_rgba` and `ax.text(2,2,"Test", color='black', backgroundcolor=to_rgba('red', alpha=0.3))`.